# C3.js samples just don't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Some weird stuff is happening to me with this library.
I am trying to execute this samples that came with the package, but they do not work.

My browser (Firefox and Chrome) seem not to find c3.css and c3.js. They were shortcuts, so I replaced them with the original source but nothing changed.

Then I try to implement the most basic chart following the getting started guide (two bunch of code you just have to copy) but nothing happen (there is no chart). In this case no error is thrown.

c3.js Version tested: 0.4.8 and 0.4.7

The d3.js version comes from: http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

Comment: any links?/fiddle we can see?

Comment: Sorry! I realise my mistake! I was including my code before declaring <div id="chart"></div> so c3.js didn't find this div. It was an stupid mistake.

Comment: So answer the question and mark it closed so it doesn't show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include your d3 script after declaring the div:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Or place it inside an 'onload' function. Otherwise your code won't find this div.